# hibernate many-to-one создает один объект для двух разных полей класса

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Доброго времени суток. Есть таблица БД с записями о товарах. В этой таблице есть поля basePackageId и mainPackageId. Они связаны с таблицей Packages в которой хранятся данные по упаковке в виде Id, packageName. Эти таблицы связаны по внешнему ключу Id. При получении товаров из базы если в поля basePackageId и mainPackageId записаны одинаковые значения id, то Hibernate создает один объект для обоих этих полей, а нужно два отдельных объекта.

Класс Goods

```
public class Goods  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private Contragents contragents;
 private GoodsType goodsType;
 private Packages packagesByBasePackageId;
 private Packages packagesByMainPackageId;
 private Sertificates sertificates;
 private String code;
 private String name;
 private Double basePackageMass;
 private Double mainPackageMass;
 private Double mainFactor;
 private Boolean useBasePackage;
 private Double remainder;
 private Double factRemainder;
 private Double reserve;
 private Set priceses = new HashSet(0);
 private Set priceLogs = new HashSet(0);

public Goods() {
}

public Goods(Contragents contragents, GoodsType goodsType, Packages packagesByBasePackageId, Packages packagesByMainPackageId, Sertificates sertificates, String code, String name, Double basePackageMass, Double mainPackageMass, Double mainFactor, Boolean useBasePackage, Double remainder, Double factRemainder, Double reserve, Set priceses, Set priceLogs) {
   this.contragents = contragents;
   this.goodsType = goodsType;
   this.packagesByBasePackageId = packagesByBasePackageId;
   this.packagesByMainPackageId = packagesByMainPackageId;
   this.sertificates = sertificates;
   this.code = code;
   this.name = name;
   this.basePackageMass = basePackageMass;
   this.mainPackageMass = mainPackageMass;
   this.mainFactor = mainFactor;
   this.useBasePackage = useBasePackage;
   this.remainder = remainder;
   this.factRemainder = factRemainder;
   this.reserve = reserve;
   this.priceses = priceses;
   this.priceLogs = priceLogs;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Contragents getContragents() {
    return this.contragents;
}

public void setContragents(Contragents contragents) {
    this.contragents = contragents;
}
public GoodsType getGoodsType() {
    return this.goodsType;
}

public void setGoodsType(GoodsType goodsType) {
    this.goodsType = goodsType;
}
public Packages getPackagesByBasePackageId() {
    return this.packagesByBasePackageId;
}

public void setPackagesByBasePackageId(Packages packagesByBasePackageId) {
    this.packagesByBasePackageId = packagesByBasePackageId;
}
public Packages getPackagesByMainPackageId() {
    return this.packagesByMainPackageId;
}

public void setPackagesByMainPackageId(Packages packagesByMainPackageId) {
    this.packagesByMainPackageId = packagesByMainPackageId;
}
public Sertificates getSertificates() {
    return this.sertificates;
}

public void setSertificates(Sertificates sertificates) {
    this.sertificates = sertificates;
}
public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Double getBasePackageMass() {
    return this.basePackageMass;
}

public void setBasePackageMass(Double basePackageMass) {
    this.basePackageMass = basePackageMass;
}
public Double getMainPackageMass() {
    return this.mainPackageMass;
}

public void setMainPackageMass(Double mainPackageMass) {
    this.mainPackageMass = mainPackageMass;
}
public Double getMainFactor() {
    return this.mainFactor;
}

public void setMainFactor(Double mainFactor) {
    this.mainFactor = mainFactor;
}
public Boolean getUseBasePackage() {
    return this.useBasePackage;
}

public void setUseBasePackage(Boolean useBasePackage) {
    this.useBasePackage = useBasePackage;
}
public Double getRemainder() {
    return this.remainder;
}

public void setRemainder(Double remainder) {
    this.remainder = remainder;
}
public Double getFactRemainder() {
    return this.factRemainder;
}

public void setFactRemainder(Double factRemainder) {
    this.factRemainder = factRemainder;
}
public Double getReserve() {
    return this.reserve;
}

public void setReserve(Double reserve) {
    this.reserve = reserve;
}
public Set getPriceses() {
    return this.priceses;
}

public void setPriceses(Set priceses) {
    this.priceses = priceses;
}
public Set getPriceLogs() {
    return this.priceLogs;
}

public void setPriceLogs(Set priceLogs) {
    this.priceLogs = priceLogs;
}
```

Класс Packages

```
public class Packages  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private String packageName;
 private Set goodsesForBasePackageId = new HashSet(0);
 private Set goodsesForMainPackageId = new HashSet(0);

public Packages() {
}

public Packages(String packageName, Set goodsesForBasePackageId, Set goodsesForMainPackageId) {
   this.packageName = packageName;
   this.goodsesForBasePackageId = goodsesForBasePackageId;
   this.goodsesForMainPackageId = goodsesForMainPackageId;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getPackageName() {
    return this.packageName;
}

public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
    this.packageName = packageName;
}
public Set getGoodsesForBasePackageId() {
    return this.goodsesForBasePackageId;
}

public void setGoodsesForBasePackageId(Set goodsesForBasePackageId) {
    this.goodsesForBasePackageId = goodsesForBasePackageId;
}
public Set getGoodsesForMainPackageId() {
    return this.goodsesForMainPackageId;
}

public void setGoodsesForMainPackageId(Set goodsesForMainPackageId) {
    this.goodsesForMainPackageId = goodsesForMainPackageId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
    hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.packageName);
    hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.goodsesForBasePackageId);
    hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.goodsesForMainPackageId);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Packages other = (Packages) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.packageName, other.packageName)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.goodsesForBasePackageId, other.goodsesForBasePackageId)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.goodsesForMainPackageId, other.goodsesForMainPackageId)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Mapping Goods.java

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.Goods" table="goods" catalog="stock" optimistic-lock="version" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="contragents" class="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.Contragents" fetch="select">
        <column name="provider_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="goodsType" class="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.GoodsType" fetch="select">
        <column name="type_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="packagesByBasePackageId" class="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.Packages" fetch="select">
        <column name="base_package_id" unique="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="packagesByMainPackageId" class="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.Packages" fetch="select">
        <column name="main_package_id" unique="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="sertificates" class="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.Sertificates" fetch="select">
        <column name="sert_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="code" type="string">
        <column name="code" length="45" unique="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="basePackageMass" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="base_package_mass" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="mainPackageMass" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="main_package_mass" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="mainFactor" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="main_factor" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="useBasePackage" type="java.lang.Boolean">
        <column name="use_base_package" />
    </property>
    <property name="remainder" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="remainder" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="factRemainder" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="fact_remainder" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="reserve" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="reserve" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <set name="priceses" table="prices" inverse="true"  fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="good_id" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.Prices" />
    </set>
    <set name="priceLogs" table="price_log" inverse="true"  fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="good_id" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.PriceLog" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Mapping Packages.java

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.Packages" table="packages" catalog="stock" optimistic-lock="version" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="packageName" type="string">
        <column name="package_name" length="45" unique="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="goodsesForBasePackageId" table="goods" inverse="true"  fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="base_package_id" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.Goods" />
    </set>
    <set name="goodsesForMainPackageId" table="goods" inverse="true"  fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="main_package_id" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="ru.funkdevelop.stockv.pojos.Goods" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Comment: А с чего ты одинаковые Id им даешь, разные давац

Comment: У товара может быть 2 одинаковых типа фасовки. с разными типами фасовки работает без проблем

Comment: создавай два разных объекта с разными Id,  и вообще в чем проблема,  что обьект один

Comment: в том и вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при получении товара из базы средствами Hibernate создавались 2 разных объекта при любых значениях ID типа фасовки?

Comment: Всё вполне логично, одинаковые Id одинаковые объекты. Другому быть не дано.

Comment: @turik1303 никак, а в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Пусть и не самым изящным образом.
В сеттере клонирую объект передаваемый в сеттер.

Answer (score 0):

turik1303 так и не объяснил зачем нужно 2 объекта.
Hibernate не может создать два персистных объекта с одним ID. Если эти два объекта разъедутся (станут отличаться), то Hibernate не сможет понять как это отразить в БД.
Когда персистный объект клонируется в сеттере, то получается новый транзиентный, до которого Hibernate нет никакого дела. Если такой объект изменить, то Hibernate не отразит это в БД.
При клонировании объекта в сеттере проблема может остаться если загрузить второй товар и его упаковка будет как у загруженного первого товара